# django minutes between two datetimes

Tags: python, django, datetime

I know this question has been asked before and I've worked through the various answers along with the docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects but I still haven't been able to calculate the minutes between two datetime fields.

Here is the model:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    activity_type = models.IntegerField(default=0) 

    def time_posted_description(self):
        now = datetime.now()
        then = datetime.fromtimestamp(self.created_date)
        tdelta = now - then
        minutes = tdelta.total_minutes()

        return minutes
```

The View:

def portal_game_activity_page(request):

```
activity = Activity.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-created_date')

pending_requests_list = FriendshipRequest.objects.filter(to_user=request.user, accepted=False)
number_pending_requests = len(pending_requests_list)

return render(request, 'portal/portal_game_activity.html', {'game_activity_page': True,'number_pending_requests':number_pending_requests,'activity':activity, })
```

And the template:

```
{% extends "portal/portal_base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <section>
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                {% for event in activity %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{event.user}}</td>
                    <td>{{event.created_date}}</td>
                    <td>{{event.time_posted_description}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>    
    </section>
{% endblock %}
```

Any feedback/assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

```
now = datetime.now()
then = self.created_date
tdelta = now - then
minutes = tdelta.total_seconds() / 60

return minutes
```

Comment: I am not getting any value from "minutes". I've tried print "total minutes %d" % minutes Any thoughts?

Comment: I just added the view and template code above. I appreciate the feedback

Comment: does the page load? is that table field just empty? created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now) this should be datetime.datetime.now() or datetime.now() (depending on your import) imo

Comment: Yes the page does load with the {{event.time_posted_description}} field empty. The (default=datetime.now) seems to be saving properly do you think not using datetime.now() can be part of the issue why I'm not getting a value for minutes?

Answer (score 0):

datetime.fromtimestamp get timestamp argument:

```
    then = datetime.fromtimestamp(self.created_date.second)
```

'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'total_minutes'